# Display Wordpress Sidebar on External Website

Tags: wordpress, iframe, file-get-contents, sidebar

How to display wordpress sidebar information on an external php site.

Tried by `iframe` but, fails when clicking links in iframe; which loads page in iframe only. actually i would like to go wordpress site when click from the external site.

Tried by `file_get_content()` method but it also fails to display twitter feeds from wordpress sidebar.

Any help to overcome the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the sidebar in an HTML file and have this file updated every time a post is found. Rather than post all the code, here is the source of the information I have previously looked at.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/display-wordpress-sidebar-on-other-non-wp-sites/